# ng2-slider-component support in webpack

Tags: angular, webpack

I am trying to get a Slider on my angular 2 webpage, but unable to get that using ng2-slider-component.
In the App's module i added below:

```
@NgModule({.......declarations: Ng2SliderComponent.........})
```

and in MyComponent's html i added:

```
<ng2-slider 
min="6"
max="23"
startValue="9"
endValue="21"
stepValue="2"
[normalHandlerStyle]="{ 'background-color': 'green'}"
[slidingHandlerStyle]="{
      'border-radius': '9px',
      'background-color': 'red'
}">
```

but when i run above, i get below 2 errors:

1) On cmd line, when i run npm start, i get below error:

```
ERROR in ./~/ng2-slider-component/ng2-slider.component.html
[0] Module parse failed:    D:\Abc\Angular2\Projects\SPA4\Project\node_modules\ng2-slider-component\ng2-slider.component.html Unexpected token (1:0)
[0] You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
[0] SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:0)
[0]     at Parser.pp$4.raise  (D:\Abc\Angular2\Projects\SPA4\Project\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2221:15)
[0]     at Parser.pp.unexpected (D:\Abc\Angular2\Projects\SPA4\Project\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:603:10)
[0]     at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (D:\Abc\Angular2\Projects\SPA4\Project\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1822:12)
[0]     at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (D:\Abc\Angular2\Projects\SPA4\Project\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1715:21)
.........
.........
```

2) When i run localhost:3000 on browser, i get below error:

```
main.js:18187 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./ng2-slider.component.html"(…)
webpackMissingModule @ main.js:18187
(anonymous function) @ main.js:18187
(anonymous function) @ main.js:18194
__webpack_require__ @ vendor.js:51
(anonymous function) @ main.js:74
__webpack_require__ @ vendor.js:51
(anonymous function) @ main.js:7
__webpack_require__ @ vendor.js:51
webpackJsonpCallback @ vendor.js:22
(anonymous function) @ main.js:1
```

Please guide how to resolve errors and get slider on my page..

Answer (score 1):

Currently ng2-slider-component doesn't seems to be supporting webpack configuration. I am saying this because line 34 is commented here https://github.com/Bogdan1975/ng2-slider-component/blob/master/ng2-slider.component.ts

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: The given link works for me, couldn't understand if you wanted to say something else.